# Java LinkedList Search

Tags: java

I need some help with a Java linked list. I need to be able to search for people last names, phone numbers etc. 
Here is my code so far.

```
LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
  String peopleFile = "res/people.txt";
  int id = 1;
  try (BufferedReader fin = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(peopleFile)))
  {
     String line = fin.readLine();
     while (line != null)
     {
        String[] clientLine = line.split(";");
        Property comprop = new CommercialProperty(id, clientLine[0], clientLine[1],
                clientLine[2], clientLine[3], Double.parseDouble(clientLine[4]),
                clientLine[5], clientLine[6], Integer.parseInt(clientLine[7]));
        list.add(comprop);
        line = fin.readLine();
        id++;
     }
     fin.close();
  }
  catch (FileNotFoundException e)
  {
  }
  catch (IOException e)
  {
  }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your custom class has such methods as `getLastName()`, `getPhoneNumber()`, etc. You can search for objects that satisfy a certain condition using [`filter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-).

For example:

```
static List<ComercialProperty> propertyWithLastName(List<ComercialProperty> list, String name) {
    return list.stream().filter(p -> name.equals(p.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This will return a `List<ComercialProperty>` containing every instance where `getName()` has the same value as `name`.

Also, you should avoid using raw types. When creating a list, you should say which object type the list will store:

```
List<CommercialProperty> list = new LinkedList<>();
```

Note I used `CommercialProperty` instead of `Property` because it looks like you want to use methods specific to the `CommercialProperty` class.